# Unable to locate element using ID, XPath and CSS Selector

Tags: c#, angular, selenium, automated-tests, atata

I am using atata framework with C#. I am trying to locate web element to select all rows but neither Id, CSS Path or XPath are able to find.

I have used ID, XPath and CSS Selector

```
[FindById("com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall")]
public Button<_> SelectAllRows { get; private set; }

[FindByXPath("div[@id=com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall]")]
public Button<_> SelectAllRows { get; private set; }
```

My page object should be located. Details of paths are:

Element:

```
<div class="widget-button btn-group margin-mini shrinkable" title="Select All Rows" 
id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall" style="display: inline-block;">

<div class="top-bar"><span></span></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded widget-button-icon" id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn">
<i class="icon-k-select-all"></i></button><div class="icon-label"><span>Select All Rows</span></div></div>
```

Selector: #com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall

XPath: //*[@id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall"]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the ID in single quotes for your selector? `div[@id='com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall']`

Comment: Yes i just did, it still doesn't find element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For the first `<div>` element:

   ```html
   <div class="widget-button btn-group margin-mini shrinkable" title="Select All Rows" 
   id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall" style="display: inline-block;">
   ```

   As it is a `div`, not a `button` element then use general puprose `Control` type:

   ```cs
   [FindById("com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall")]
   public Control<_> SelectAllRows { get; private set; }
   ```
2. For the second `<button>` element:

   ```html
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded widget-button-icon" id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn">
   ```

   The following should find the element if it's actually visible:

   ```cs
   [FindById("com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn")]
   public Button<_> SelectAllRows { get; private set; }
   ```

   If the element is not visible:

   ```cs
   [FindById("com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn", Visibility = Visibility.Any)]
   public Button<_> SelectAllRows { get; private set; }
   ```

Anyway, figure out which element is actually visible and should be interacted with.

Comment: I have tried with following pairs in Find and yet it is unable to locate element: FindByClass nd Control for Div element srch, Find by Id nd Control for Div element srch, FindbyClass and Button for btn class and Find by id and Button for srch Here is the web elmnt info: <div class="widget-button btn-group margin-mini shrinkable" title="Select All Rows" id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall" <div class="top-bar"><button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded widget-button-icon"id="com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn"><i class="icon-k-select-all"><div class="icon-label">
Select All Rows

Comment: Please verify the hierarchy of these elements for iframes and shadow DOM elements in ancestors. That can be a reason. Also try to find these elements using pure WebDriver, like `AtataContext.Current.Driver.FindElement(By...)`.

Comment: I had to switch frame to locate element. thanks for input! you are a Guru

Answer (score 1):

I think you should perform the click action on the `button` element instead of the `div` element. Try the below code:

```
[FindById("com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn")]
public Button<_> SelectAllRows { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I tried but it does not locate element: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unable to locate element: By.XPath: .//*[normalize-space(@id) = 'com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn']/descendant-or-self::*[self::input[@type='button' or @type='submit' or @type='reset'] or self::button]

Comment: I think all you need to do is to look for this id "com.kronos.wfc.ngui.genies.selectall_btn"

Comment: I had to switch frame to locate element. thanks for input!